# Download several files with wget in parallel

Tags: bash, wget, parallelism

I have the following bash script:

```
for i in {0800..9999}; do
    for j in {001..032}; do
        wget http://example.com/"$i-$j".jpg
    done
done
```

All photos are exist and in fact each iteration does not depend from another. How to parallelize it with possibility of control the number of threads?

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7577615/parallel-wget-in-bash

Comment: Wasn't it one of the principle designs of Wget to not support such practices as this?  Are you not interested in a download accelerator?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Confiq's answer is a good one for small `i` and `j`.  However, given the size of `i` and `j` in your question, you will likely want to limit the overall number of processes spawned.  You can do this with the `parallel` command or some versions of `xargs`.  For example, using an xargs that supports the `-P` flag you could parallelize your inner loop as follows:

```
for i in {0800..9999}; do
  echo {001..032} | xargs -n 1 -P 8 -I{} wget http://example.com/"$i-{}".jpg
done
```

[GNU parallel](https://www.gnu.org/software/parallel/) has a large number of features for when you need more sophisticated behavior and makes it easy to parallelize over both parameters:

```
parallel -a <(seq 0800 9999) -a <(seq 001 032) -P 8 wget http://example.com/{1}-{2}.jpg
```

Comment: Using `parallel` looks very cool and simple, thanks!

Comment: There's also `xjobs`, which is similar to `xargs -P`.

Comment: See the comparison between GNU Parallel and xjobs https://www.gnu.org/software/parallel/parallel_alternatives.html#DIFFERENCES-BETWEEN-xjobs-AND-GNU-Parallel

Answer (score 4):

Here's a very simplistic approach.  Limits threads to 10 in this example.

```
for i in {0800..9999}; do
    for j in {001..032}; do
        wget http://example.com/"$i-$j".jpg &
        while test $(jobs -p|wc -w) -ge 10; do sleep 0.1 ; done
    done
done
```

Answer (score 3):

```
for i in {1..3}; do
    for j in {10..20}; do
        (wget http://example.com/"$i-$j".jpg &)
    done
done
```

I even tested it...

Comment: It's too many threads I think. It should be possible to limit the number of threads

Comment: well, that's not your original question... maybe you should update the question then?

Comment: _You_ have modified the original question. As per the original, your solution spawns nearly 300000 processes which is of course ridiculous.

Comment: @pipe: if you would read comments, you would see that OP has edited the question

Comment: The original question has an outer loop from 800 to 9999 and an inner loop from 1 to 32. You changed that to something _much_ smaller in order for your solution to work.

Answer (score 2):

Here's roughly how I solved the same problem in an environment where `parallel` wasn't available. This relies on bash features, so you need `#!/bin/bash` or explicitly executing the script through bash.

```
MAX_CONCURRENT=50
n=0
some_command_that_outputs_urls \
| while read url
do
    {
        do_something_with $url
    } &
    PIDS="$PIDS $!"

    ((++n))
    if test "$n" -ge "$MAX_CONCURRENT"
    then
        n=0
        wait $PIDS
        PIDS=""
    fi
done
test -n "$PIDS" && wait $PIDS
```

You can adjust `$MAX_CONCURRENT` to specify the desired (approximate) maximum number of threads. And of course, you'll replace `some_command_that_outputs_urls` and `do_something_with $url` with whatever happens to be appropriate in your scenario. For example, you might replace the line `some_command_that_outputs_urls \` with

```
for i in {0800..9999}; do
    for j in {001..032}; do
        printf 'http://example.com/%s-%s.jpg\n' $i $j
    done
done \
# ...| while read url ...
```

and `do_something_with $url` with simply

```
wget $url
```

giving you the final result

```
MAX_CONCURRENT=50
n=0
for i in {0800..9999}; do
    for j in {001..032}; do
        printf 'http://example.com/%s-%s.jpg\n' $i $j
    done
done \
| while read url
do
    {
        wget $url
    } &
    PIDS="$PIDS $!"

    ((++n))
    if test "$n" -ge "$MAX_CONCURRENT"
    then
        n=0
        wait $PIDS
        PIDS=""
    fi
done
test -n "$PIDS" && wait $PIDS
```

The way this works is to have a command that generates the list of (in this case) URLs on its standard output, and read that one line at a time into the `while` loop (watch out for newlines!). It will spawn up to `$MAX_CONCURRENT` simultaneous processes, using `$n` to keep track of how many have been spawned and `$PIDS` to record their process IDs. Once `$MAX_CONCURRENT` processes have been spawned (note that what's really being spawned is a compound statement, so you can have multiple commands and even blocks within it), it will `wait` on the spawned PIDs (this returns immediately if none of the specified PIDs are still executing) and reset its internal state, then proceed with another run.

There are several ways that this script could be improved, including better handling of reused PIDs, but it does the job I wanted it to do in the environment where it needed to run, so it's good enough for me. In my actual version, there's also a timeout in place, and it is re-executed regularly via cron, so the risk of runaway execution times is much reduced compared to this simpler version.

Comment: If GNU Parallel is not available you should probably read this first: http://oletange.blogspot.dk/2013/04/why-not-install-gnu-parallel.html